# Safe to restart after hanging update to 18.04 desktop?

Tags: 18.04

Tried to upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04, two hours in, the thing seems to be frozen, and from the desktop I can't get a response from anything I click on e.g. no application will open.

If I do `Ctrl+Alt+F4` I can get a terminal (full screen) to login as my user. The terminal shows text `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS [MY-USER] tty4`

After logging in I see a welcome set of text:

`Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS....
...
...
*** System restart required ***...
...`

When I try via `reboot` I get a warning to say that `Operation inhibited by "UpdateManager" PID 11087...reason is "Updating System"`

So...should I force the reboot or is there a way to *see* what `updatemanager` is doing/its status?

Comment: You could run `top` to check if the upgrade is still on. If not, foce-reboot, and you might need to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to complete the upgrade.

Comment: What in `top` should I look for?

Comment: There appears to be nothing using CPU. But I'm not that "expert" with `top` so anything specific I should look for?

Comment: Sould be high cpu activity at the top of the list of processes. If the CPU is quiet, just reboot. Package installation should be resource intensive.

Comment: Headline is: all when well, so good advise. I had to do a few restarts as it got into a loop on the first attempt at restarting but eventually I made it to the desktop. I then did the `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and a `sudo apt --fix-broken` and eventually the warning about a failed install went away and I have a working 18.04 LTS installed. If you make your comment an answer I can accept it.